# GLSurfaceView crashes on device rotation / orientation change - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView that previews the camera and works fine in portrait. I've started to try and implement recording video in landscape, but get a strange error when the orientation changes.

I do not override the `OnConfigurationChanged` method, and do not have `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` configured in my manifest, though, I achieved the same error when trying to handle the orientation change this way as well. For the layout, I have both a portrait and landscape version (landscape in layout-land folder). My reason for doing this is research online seemed to indicate that GLSurfaceView should be able to handle screen rotation.

Main questions:

1. What is the most common cause of the error above?
2. Is this the correct approach for handling screen orientation changes with a GLSurface View?
3. If not, what is?

**Error:**

```
2020-04-26 18:02:24.559 6197-6197/XXX.XXX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: XXX.XXX, PID: 6197
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.surfaceCreated()' on a null object reference
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:557)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:805)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:210)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2809)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1663)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7546)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:916)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:718)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:650)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:902)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Root View -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainActivityLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="XXX.XXX.MainActivity">

<!-- AspectFrameLayout that contains the GLSurfaceView -->
<XXX.XXX.AspectFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview_afl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/libraryButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/libraryButton"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <!-- GLSurfaceView displaying camera preview -->
    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview_surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>

</XXX.XXX.AspectFrameLayout>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="XXX.XXX.MainActivity">

<!-- Buttons go here to appear over the preview -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OnCreate Method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_capture);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an OrientationListener and implementing a "simulated" landscape experience when the device is rotated to avoid interrupting the camera capture and triggering the error. So technically, my app stays in "Portrait" all the time, but the UI is updated when the device is rotated.

I am not convinced this is the right approach, and would welcome a better solution that leverages Android's existing methods for handling orientation change.

The specific use case Android's approach does not address - if you want to prevent an orientation change based on logic, in my case, if the user has already began recording in a specific orientation. In Swift/IOS, this can be achieved with the shouldAutorotate method.